# Choose the format of Date of an attribute in The Entity Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using **Spring Data Jpa** , and I want an annontation to make it up on the attribute to choose the format of date. I look for some annotations but I don't found nothing. 
I want something like this :

```
@Entity 
public class User(){

......(format dd/mm/aa)
private Date birthDay;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Temporal won’t help here man, he want to set format of date. Share code to us, let us also know how to format date format using Temporal

Comment: If you want to store the date as in a database in a certain format then you can use the `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")` annotation and state what pattern you want

Comment: @user9065831 actually you are wrong. Temporal is the right choice for the java.util.Date like in the code in question. Dates can be different - you must use the right annotation for the specific date. For members of the java.util package use 
Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) or Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) or Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Spring `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat` which has several date formats.

In your entity annotate your `birthDay` property

```java
@Entity
public class User() {

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date birthDay;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For stating what pattern you want when storing into a database you can use the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation.

```
@Entity 
public class User {

    @DateTimeFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date birthDay; 
}
```

There are a lot of standard formats or you can set your own custom format.

[DateTimeFormatter.class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe @DateTimeFormat has nothing to do with how the date (time) is stored in the database - it is used in combination with @RequestParam  to parse HttpRequest parameters. Like that:

```
@GetMapping("/getbybirthdate")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Client>> getClientByBirthdate(@RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size, @RequestParam  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") LocalDate birthdate) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(clientService.getClientsByBirthdate(page,  size, birthdate));
    }
```

If you try to map date/time types from java.util package then @Temporal is the right choice.
If you try to map java.time types then there's no need to explicitly specify any mapping annotation except for @Basic or @Column (that's what Baeldung advises to have - but I believe neither @Basic nor @Column is needed for mapping, they are needed only for their extra attributes)

BUT
if the problem is in parsing of String values as date-time then in the case of java.time types please use

```
LocalDate.parse("2017-11-15")
LocalTime.parse("15:30:18")
LocalDateTime.parse("2017-11-15T08:22:12")
Instant.parse("2017-11-15T08:22:12Z")
```

or for the format other than ISO use DateTimeFormatter class:

```
LocalDate.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse("2018-03-09"))
```

and in the case of the java.util types:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-11-15")
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("15:30:14")
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2017-11-15 15:30:14.332")
```